# PySimpleGUI. RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python, multithreading

As a Python learner I decided to try out PySimpleGUI, and wrote a script in which the relevant snippet is:

```
`    
import PySimpleGUI as sg 
....
window = sg.Window('Output Filename Creator').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None  or event == "Cancel":
        window.Close()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        outfile = values['file']
        window.Close()
        return outfile    `
```

I use Windows 10, Python 3.7, Idle 3.7, and PySimpleGUI-3.24.0. After running the script that contains the snippet above (no execution errors) I go to the Idle shell and try to type in len('1'). At entering the open bracket the following error is generated:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 332, in __del__
    if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`

I know that PySimpleGUI is based on tkinter, but that is as far as my knowledge goes. I don't know how threading works in Python or how PySimpleGUI is interfaced with Tk. Yet I would like to know where the error comes from and what I can do to avoid it.

Update: the code reduced to bare essentials still gives the same error when window is closed by clicking on cross in upper right corner:

```
def OutputFileName(default):
    import PySimpleGUI as sg      

    layout = [
              [sg.In(default, key='file', size=(70,1)),
               sg.SaveAs('Browse')],
              [sg.Save(), sg.Text(' '*35), sg.Cancel()]
            ]

    window = sg.Window(' ').Layout(layout)
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or event == "Cancel":
        return
    elif event == 'Save':
        return values['file']
outf = OutputFileName('foo.txt')
```

Comment: It seems that you cannot go in the loop a second time as in both branches of the `if statement` you exit the loop, so why the need for `while True:`?

Comment: The PySimpleGUI documentation gave me the impression that you must loop over events -- such as keyboard presses. Anyway, I took the loop out and the error still occurs.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment: I modified an example in which  sg.Window() was invoked with the argument 'return_keyboard_events=True'. I overlooked  this argument and did not include it, obviating  an infinite loop.

Comment: Remove the `window.Close()` from the `while True:` loop. Follow this pattern [persistent-window-multiple-reads-using-an-event-loop-updates-data-in-window](https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/#pattern-2-b-persistent-window-multiple-reads-using-an-event-loop-updates-data-in-window)

Comment: Took Close() out of the loop (twice). Added 'do_not_clear=True' to In(...) as in link. Problem persists.

Comment: If I remove window.Close() completely from the code and close the window by clicking the red cross in the upper right hand corner, problem persists.

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded?  This kind of error can occur if a different thread frees up resources.  I suggest logging an issue on the project's github site (http://www.PySimpleGUI.com).

Comment: I don't know if it is multi-threaded, as I wrote above.

Comment: IDLE and PySimpleGUI are both using tkinter.  I think this problem is happening because you're accessing the PySimpleGUI code through the IDLE shell. If you run this program outside of IDLE do you see this error?

Comment: When I mainline the code (code outside function) it works perfectly. Including in function gives multi-threading?

Comment: You're going to see inconsistent, random feeling, illogical readings as long as you attempt to use IDLE with tkinter or PySimpleGUI.  Lots of hits found in the Google-machine when searching about tkinter/IDLE interactions and problems trying to debug tkinter programs in IDLE.  Switch IDE to PyCharm and your problems will stop.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is due to IDLE being written using tkinter.

tkinter is very picky about resources and threads.  There is a warning in the PySimpleGUI documentation about utilizing PySimpleGUI in a threaded environment because you can get into situations like this one where resources are freed in the incorrect thread or tkinter gets confused about who is running the mainloop.

Here is an older post that talks about problems running multiple mainloops when using IDLE.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/kr7lKj4qMl4